# Clamp LookAtMouse Z Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that looks at mouse position, but it has no limits. For example, if the object's rotation is greater than 40 or less -40 then it does not rotate.

```
public class GunController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxTop, minBottom;
    void Update()
    {
        var pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        var dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little function I use to clamp the rotation in an FPS up/down aim rotation.

You can modify it for your usage.

```
Quaternion ClampRotationAroundXAxis(Quaternion q)
{
    q.x /= q.w;
    q.y /= q.w;
    q.z /= q.w;
    q.w = 1.0f;

    float angleX = 2.0f * Mathf.Rad2Deg * Mathf.Atan(q.x);

    angleX = Mathf.Clamp(angleX, -90f, 90f);

    q.x = Mathf.Tan(0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad * angleX);

    return q;
}
```